# Sending GPS data and Edit Text Email using AsyncTask

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am sending multiple parameters using AsyncTask, Parameters consist of Gps data and an edit text (user input) Email.

```
public class Camera extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton ib;
Button savebutton;

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final String TAG= "PostActivity";


EditText email;
LocationManager locationmanager;
Location location;
private String latlng = "";

Double lat;
Double lng;
private String longitude;
private String latitude;
private String gemail = "";






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.photo_layout);

    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    giveMeNewLocation(location);
    TakePic();
```

//TakePic() that is called as soon as the location is collected 
    }
      // giveMeNewLocation is a method that gives us lat and long values from Location object

```
private void giveMeNewLocation(Location location) {

    if (location != null) {

         lat = location.getLatitude();
         lng = location.getLongitude();
         latitude= String.valueOf(lat);
         longitude= String.valueOf(lng);

        latlng = "Latitude:" + lat + "Longitude:" + lng;

        Toast.makeText(this, latlng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i(TAG,"Post Locations to a Server..." +latlng);
    }   
}

private void TakePic() {
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eText);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);
    savebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bProceed);

    ib.setOnClickListener(this);


}
    }

       public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String alatlng = params[0];
            String bgemail = params[1];
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<NameValuePair> p= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Locations", alatlng));
            p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", bgemail));


            // HTTP Object to send Data
            HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost post= new HttpPost("http://myipadd/Examples/LatLng.php");

            try {

                //Put data in the object
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(p));





            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Execute post Which provide a response
            HttpResponse responcee = null;
            try {
                responcee = client.execute(post);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int status=responcee.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String nstatus=String.valueOf(status);
            Log.i("Response From Server:", nstatus);

            return nstatus;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String nstatus){
             super.onPostExecute(nstatus);

             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Post Response:" +nstatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
       }



/*Explicit Intent to start Data Activity,
This is just another method of using a button without setting onClickListener,//
Instead we use the Method name in the Layout Xml file by adding  android:onClick="CollectData"*/

public void CollectData(View v) {



        gemail= email.getText().toString(); 


        new MyTask().execute(latlng,gemail);
    }

  }
```

And the Php script i used:

```
  <?php



 $db_host  = "localhost";

$db_uid  = "xxxx";

$db_pass = "xxxx";



$db_name  = "xxxx"; 



$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');



  mysql_select_db($db_name);

 $latlngdata= $_POST['Locations'];



$emaildata= $_POST['Email'];






mysql_query("INSERT INTO locations(email, latlng) VALUES ('$emaildata','$latlngdata')");

?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming your insert query could NEVER fail. Why don't you have an `or die(...)` on the `mysql_query()` call? Done any basic debugging, like checking if your php script is actually invoked?

Comment: @Marc B just wanted to find out if it works using php script taken from one of the questions posted on stackoverflow. and when i run the script using localhost/examples/LatLng.php gaved me error Warning: mysql_connect Access denied for user xxx@localhost.

Comment: Don't try to put the parameters in a database right away. Because what is your problem? That you cannot send the parameters? That php does not receive them? Or that php cannot store them in a database? You are not clear about that. Let your php script just echo Locations and Email to be sure they are received well.

Comment: Thanks guys its working now but creates empty rows in the Database , the problem was the privileges, but why does it create empty rows. it happened when i was storing location data in database but only worked when i used the TYPE=Text, i am Using TYPE=Char for storing email

Comment: ya well the emulator cant emulate lat and long so its gonna be empty but email, i will check other TYPE for storing email addresses

Comment: empty rows = your query is working but nothing's coming through from the form. `var_dump($_POST)` in PHP will show you exactly what's being received by the script.

Comment: @Marc B . Thanks for reply. Well I m getting lat and lng but the email column is empty and its something to do with Type used to store emails . I had the same problem for storing latlng and only Type-Text worked when I was creating fields in the database . Cant figure out how

Comment: Solved.. Thanks to every one.