# Android App sends Data only Using Wifi

Tags: android, httpclient

I have a question to ask, I created an Android App where i am sending Data to Xampp server (Using HttpClient) and storing it in a Database. My App does,not send Data using Mobile Network , even tried with 4G but the Application stops but works with wifi. I just wanted to know why does my App only works with Wifi and if somebody know how to make it work using Mobile network eg the way Viber works

Thanks .

Comment: can you please put your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105505/sending-gps-data-and-edit-text-email-using-asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your manifest file (which it sounds like you do, since you can do data over WiFi), you should be able to send data using HttpClient over any available network.

What I think is going on is that your Xampp server is on your local network and it is not visible from the outside of your LAN. The WiFi works, because that puts your phone in the same LAN as your server. You need to poke a hole in your firewall (router), so that outside requests can reach your local server.

Comment: I am using Permissions,Thanks for reply How do i do it(poke a hole in firewall(router)), i also have a problem sending data from android device connected to wifi at location A  to my xampp server runing on my laptop at location B using a Different wifi

Comment: This is some basic networking. You just need to have your router at location B (that your laptop with the server connects to) forward outside traffic to the laptop. How you do that depends on your router's manufacturer. You need to go to the routers admin console and go to the NAT settings. Just Google your router model and NAT. Here is some basic info on NAT: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look

Comment: so its the static NAT i need to configure, meaning having a static ip address

Comment: It would be beneficial to give your laptop a static LAN address, so that it does not change every time you restart it. Then, let's say your laptop has an IP of 192.168.1.5. And it is all http traffic, meaning it is on port 80. Then in the NAT settings of your router you will configure all traffic coming on port 80, go to 192.168.1.5:80. That is all. Then from your Android app you will be sending traffic to your internet IP address or domain. Let's say location B's IP address is 10.20.15.180. Your app will be sending all requests to that IP and the router will take care of the rest.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if that was the issue.

Comment: very helpful, directional Thanks a lot